# unable to import tensorflow in spyder,it show following error

Tags: tensorflow

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.

Comment: ... is this a question?

Comment: _"Unless you are using bazel, you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory"_... I wonder where the problem comes from